# How to solve this limit $\lim_{x \to \infty, y \to \infty} \frac{x^2+y^2}{x^4+y^4}$?

Tags: calculus, limits

As far as I know this type of limits has no general approach. so I have no clue how to solve this one:

$$\lim_{x \to \infty, y \to \infty} \frac{x^2+y^2}{x^4+y^4}$$

Can someone help me with this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In polar coordinates you have $$\lim_{(x,y)\to \infty}\dfrac{x^2+y^2}{x^4+y^4}=\lim_{\rho\to \infty}\dfrac{\rho^2}{\rho^4(\cos^4\theta+\sin^4\theta)}=\lim_{\rho\to \infty}\dfrac{1}{\rho^2(\cos^4\theta+\sin^4\theta)}=0, $$
since $\cos^4\theta+\sin^4\theta>1/2$.

Answer (score 2):

Using the AM-GM inequality, we see that

$$x^4+y^4\ge 2x^2y^2$$

Therefore, we have

$$0\le \frac{x^2+y^2}{x^4+y^4}\le \frac12\left(\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{y^2}\right)\to 0\,\,\text{as}\,\,(x,y)\to (\infty,\infty)$$

Answer (score 0):

Intuition is this should always go to zero as the denominator is of a higher order than the numerator, but we have to check that it doesn't depend on how $x$ and $y$ go to $\infty$.

So try writing $(x,y) = \lambda v$ where $v = (\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$ is on the unit circle. Then use that the numerator and denominator are homogeneous.